# How to decommission a publishsettings file generated by Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile?

Tags: powershell, azure

How can I  decommission a publishsettings file generated by Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile?

I need to make sure users who received a copy the publishsettings file cannot connect to our company's subscription anymore.

**Update 1:** 
I should have mentioned in my question that I've tried deteting the certificate from the Settings / Management Certificates section.Surprisingly, still I am able to connect, even though the certificate is deleted from the Settings / Management Certificates section.

Also I have deleted the file AzureProfile.json from %appdata%\Windows Azure Powershell. Still I can do Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile with the .publishsettings file !!!

Am I missing anything?

**Update2:**
Ok, @Neil Mackenzie is right.

Here is what I was missing. When the certificate is deleted, still the entry exists in the file  %appdata%\Windows Azure Powershell\AzureProfile.json. THAT IS WHAT Get-AzureSubscription RETURNS, and that confused me. I though I am authenticated if I can call GetAzureSubscription. I was wrong. As soon as I tried to call a command that requires authentication, I got an error explained the certificate is invalid.

You can take a look and see that the account entries in AzureProfile.json is the actual certificate's thumbprint in the portal's Settings / Management Certificates section. If the thumbprint is missing, the authentication fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the Settings / Management Certificates section of the Azure Production Portal and delete the certificate from there. It will no longer be usable as a certificate to authenticate management operations.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my question that I've tried that and surprisingly still I am able to connect, even though the certificate is deleted from the Settings / Management Certificates section.

Comment: Once the certificate is deleted you should not be able to authenticate with it.   If you are using PowerShell you should use Get-AzureSubscription to verify the subscription and authentication details.

In fact, you should stop using certificates and start using AAD authentication. Certificates are only usable with ASM mode PowerShell and don't work with ARM mode PowerShell.